# How to test a full software system on incremental changes deep in the dependency tree?

Tags: architecture, continuous-integration, automated-tests, integration-testing

I'm in pursuit of a system that can be run on a project (generally in CI) that enables the automated testing of all dependents' projects with the introduced change.  Further, if a dependent project is opt-ing in, I would want to propagate tests up to *its* dependents and so on.

Does such a system already exist?

Here's a hypothetical thing to ease conversation on the topic.

Suppose you ship a ATHING™.

- ATHING™ is system, not just an executable.
- ATHING™ is composed of carefully orchestrated & independent components and/or sub-systems

  - For simplicity, lets say ATHING™ is composed of ATHING-DB™, ATHING-REST-API™, ATHING-UI™, and ATHING-WidgetMicroService™.
- All services in ATHING™ are well tested, and e2e tests exist at the top level.

Now suppose you make a change.  Suppose that the change is in just one component of your system--updating one of the *libraries* used in the REST API.  What does that process look like?

- You clone ATHING-REST-API™ source & update the lib
- You push your changes, do code review, and (hopefully) you wait for CI to tell you that your *unit tests* pass
- You merge
  You wait for some higher-level build of ATHING™ to kick out, and you maybe test that system works.

What's missing here is that high-level integration tests are not run on incremental changes down the dependency graph.  The lack of consistent, fast, full-system integration tests is a pain for everyone who works in the system.  On-change full system integration tests generally happen after a change is committed, merged, & rippled through the build system--not before, where it should be, in order to prevent garbage-in-garbage-out.

So, what do people know?  Have you tried something like this?  Surely feasibility depends on the architecture of the system--but assume that the capability to build, fetch, and run all system components on a single box is achievable.  Achieving this goal is not suddenly easy with docker, however, I foresee that it is suddenly easier, possibly with low cost.  Maybe some dockery-solutions exist?

Thx!